# How do I combine array if two variations is checked?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Example of my checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/8PVZ5/1/

When I check `sizes` the output will be like this

[image]

If I checked both or more variations, can I combine them be like this.

[image]

My array output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Sizes
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => S
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => L
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => M
                            [parent] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Colors
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [name] => Blue
                            [parent] => 5
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [name] => Yellow
                            [parent] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What result you want to have?

Comment: @ArtemL on second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

- First create an array containing all the colors
- Loop through all the sizes and add the colors to each one (see code below)

  ```
  $colors = array();
  $colorsChildren = $yourColorArray['children'];
  foreach($colorsChildren as $color): // loop through all the individual color options
      $colors[] = $color; //add the color and it's data to the array;
  endforeach;

  $combinedArray = array();
  $sizeChildren = $yourSizeArray['children'];
  foreach($sizeChildren as $size):
      $size['colors'] = $colors; // add all the colors to each size
      $combinedArray[] = $size; // add the size (with the colors) to the new array
  endforeach;
  ```

Comment: +1 how about if I have more variations? example colors, sizes, etc

Comment: just create an array with all the options (copy the first section of the code - changing the variables), and then add them in the second chunk of code. for example: $size['otherspecs'] = $otherSpecs.

Answer (score 1):

I put together a jQuery logic, which greps the fields of your colors table and replace / append them to the orignal table with the sizes:

```
$("#v1").on("click", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(".v1").show()
    } else {
        $(".v1").hide()
    }
});
$("#v2").on("click", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        if(!$('.v1').hasClass('colorfields')) {
            $('.v1').addClass('colorfields');
            var $add = $('.v2').find('tr:gt(0)');
            $('.v1').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
                var $row = $(this),
                    size = $row.find('td:eq(0)').text();
                $add.clone().each(function() {
                    var $newRow = $(this);
                    $newRow.insertAfter($row).addClass('with-col');
                    $newRow.prepend('<td>'+size+'</td>');
                    $newRow.find('input').each(function() {
                        var fieldname = $(this).attr('name').toString(),
                        newName = fieldname.replace(/field/g,'field['+size.toLowerCase()+']');
                        $(this).attr('name',newName);
                    });
                });
                $('.v1').find('tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)').attr('colspan',7);
                $row.addClass('no-col').hide();
            }); 
        } else { 
            $('.no-col').hide();
            $('.with-col').show();
        }
    } else {
        $('.no-col').show();
        $('.with-col').hide();
    }
});
```

I also renamed your fields, to get an assoziative array in backend, which is a bit easier to handle. A fieldname is put together like this: field[SIZECODE][FIELDID] or, in case the color table is visible: field[SIZECODE][COLORCODE][FIELDID]. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxPjw/). This example does not handle the case when you deactivate sizes and only display colors, but (since the org color table still exists) should be no problem to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?php
//Suppose your array is like 
$tempArray = array(
    "0" => Array
        (
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Sizes",
        "parent" => 0,
        "children" => Array(
            "0" => Array("id" => 2, "name" => "S", "parent" => 1),
            "1" => Array("id" => 3, "name" => "L", "parent" => 1),
            "2" => Array("id" => 4, "name" => "M", "parent" => 1)
        )
    ),
    "1" => Array
        (
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "Colors",
        "parent" => 0,
        "children" => Array(
            "0" => Array("id" => 6, "name" => "Blue", "parent" => 5),
            "1" => Array("id" => 7, "name" => "Yellow", "parent" => 5)
        )
    )
);
?>
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
    table {border:1px solid #ddd; margin:5px; width:400px;}
td {border:1px solid #ddd; padding:5px;}
td.label { width:50px;}
.sizes,.colors,.colors_sizes{display: none;}
</style>

    <!-- Script required -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#v1").click(function () {   
        if (this.checked) {
                $(".table").show();
                if($("#v2").attr("checked")==true){
                      $(".colors_sizes").show();
                      $(".colors").hide();
                        $(".sizes").hide(); 
                }else{
                    $(".sizes").show();
                    $(".colors").hide();
                    $(".colors_sizes").hide();            
                }

        }else{
                if($("#v2").attr("checked")==true){
                    $(".table").show();
                    $(".colors_sizes").hide();
                    $(".sizes").hide();
                    $(".colors").show();                
                }else{
                $(".table").hide();
                }
            }
    });

    $("#v2").click(function () {     
        if (this.checked) {
                $(".table").show();
                if($("#v1").attr("checked")==true){
                      $(".colors_sizes").show();
                       $(".colors").hide();
                        $(".sizes").hide(); 
                }else{
                    $(".colors").show();
                    $(".sizes").hide(); 
                    $(".colors_sizes").hide();               
                }

        }else{
                if($("#v1").attr("checked")==true){
                    $(".table").show();
                    $(".colors_sizes").hide();
                    $(".colors").hide();
                    $(".sizes").show();                
                }else{
                $(".table").hide();
                }
            }
    });
    });
    </script>

    <!-- HTML and PHP code -->
    Variations : 
    <input id="v1" value="v1" type="checkbox" name="v1"> Sizes
    <input id="v2" value="v2" type="checkbox" name="v2"> Colors
    <table cellspacing="0" class="table" style="display:none;">
        <?php 
        foreach($tempArray['0']['children'] as $sizes){?>

            <tr class="sizes">
                <td><?php echo $sizes['name']; ?></td>             
                <td><input type="checkbox"/>Execute</td>
            </tr>
          <?php foreach($tempArray['1']['children'] as $colors){ ?>
            <tr class="colors">
                <td><?php echo $colors['name']; ?></td>    
                <td><input type="checkbox"/>Execute</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="colors_sizes">
                <td><?php echo $sizes['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $colors['name']; ?></td>    
                <td><input type="checkbox"/>Execute</td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How about if i have unlimited variations? let's say i have 5 variations and the foreach will loop for 5 times?